Resizing JFrame issues with a JPanel and JTable using GridBagLayout
I'm in the process of testing combining a JPanel (controls) and JTable (the data) in the same frame and have run into issues when trying to resize the JFrame that contains them.
The first issue I am hitting is that frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension (frame.getSize())) under Windows 10 does not work. It allows the user to resize the frame to half that dimension. (Uncomment that line of code to see the behaviour). I then tried to implement my own and the checkSize(); method works in setting the correct minimum size. However, I cannot pick up the "end of resizing" event to issue checkSize() and I end up with an incorrect minimum size window. I've tried a ComponentListener, HierarchyBoundsListener and MouseListener, none of which work. Releasing the mouse always seems to override the last size checkSize() setting. Is there a way to overcome this?
Not being the most experience Java Swing programmer, the second issue I'm running into is trying to get the JTable and JPanel to resize when increasing the frame size. When I increase the frame size with the mouse, both the JTable and JPanel stay the same size in the centre of the frame. I'd like the control JPanel to remain anchored in the top left and grow only horizontally, or not at all, and the JTable to grow and fill the rest of the frame, both horizontally and vertically. How do I achieve this?
Test code below.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyBoundsListener;
import java.awt.event.HierarchyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Table extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField DCFileName = new JTextField (10);
    public JTextField DChours = new JTextField (5);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Dimension d;

    public Table()
    {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        //setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        //headers for the table
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                "Id", "Name", "Hourly Rate", "Part Time"
        };

        //actual data for the table in a 2d array
        Object[][] data = new Object[30][5];
        for ( int i=0;i<30;i++) {
            data[i][0] = i;
            data[i][1] = "user"+i;
            data[i][2] = String.format("%.3f", Math.random() * 10.0);
            data[i][3] = Math.random() >0.5?true:false;
        }
        //create table with data
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);

        //add the table to the frame
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        //Add the control row
        add(setupControl(), gbc);
        //add(setupControl());
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        //Add the table below
        add(new JScrollPane(table), gbc);
        frame.setTitle("Table Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        frame.add(this);
        frame.addComponentListener(new FrameListen());
        // frame.addMouseListener(new MouseListen());
        frame.pack();
        // frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension (frame.getSize()));
        d = frame.getSize();
        /*frame.getContentPane().addHierarchyBoundsListener(new HierarchyBoundsListener(){

            @Override
            public void ancestorMoved(HierarchyEvent e) {
                checkSize();
            }

            @Override
            public void ancestorResized(HierarchyEvent e) {
            }
        }); */
        System.out.println("Size " + d.getWidth() + " " + d.getHeight());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel setupControl() {
        JPanel control = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        control.add(MakeTextField (" Rows of Data to Send", JTextField.LEFT) ,gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        control.add(DChours, gbc);
        DChours.setEditable(true);
        DChours.setText("10");
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        control.add(MakeTextField (" Data input file", JTextField.LEFT) ,gbc);
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        DCFileName.setEditable(false);
        control.add(DCFileName, gbc);
        DCFileName.setText("Input file");
        return control;

    }

    private JTextField MakeTextField(String label, int alignment) {
        return MakeTextField ( label, label.length(), alignment );
    }

    private JTextField MakeTextField(String label, int length, int alignment) {
        length = (int) (length * 0.8);
        JTextField tf = new JTextField(length);
        tf.setText(label);
        tf.setEditable(false);
        tf.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
        tf.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        return tf;
    } 

    private class MouseListen implements MouseListener{

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Mouse clicked" );

        }
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse pressed" );

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse released" );
            checkSize();

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse enter" );

        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Mouse exit" );

        }

    }

    private class FrameListen implements ComponentListener{

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            checkSize();
        }
        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Dimension d2 = frame.getSize();
        boolean resize = false;
        if (d2.getWidth() < d.getWidth()) {
            d2.setSize(d.getWidth(), d2.getHeight());
            resize = true;
        }
        if (d2.getHeight() < d.getHeight()) {
            d2.setSize(d2.getWidth(), d.getHeight());
            resize = true;
        }
        if ( resize ) frame.setSize(d2);
        System.out.println("Size " + d2.getWidth() + " " + d2.getHeight() + " " + resize);
        return;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Table();
            }
        });
    }   
}


 


You are over-complicating things. You don't need GridBagLayout. The JFrame contains a content pane that contains all the components that you add to the JFrame. This content pane is, by default, a JPanel whose layout manager is BorderLayout. Hence you simply need to create the JTable (as you have done), wrap it in a JScrollPane (as you have done) and add the JScrollPane to the JFrame.
Also, the JFrame cannot know what its size is until it is actually painted on the computer screen, so calling method getSize() before the JFrame is painted, is not going to give you your desired result.
In the below code, I use a WindowListener. Method windowOpened is invoked after the JFrame is initially displayed, hence method getSize() will return the correct value.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TablDemo extends WindowAdapter implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent event) {
        Window window = event.getWindow();
        window.setMinimumSize(window.getSize());
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame applicationWindow = new JFrame();
        applicationWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        applicationWindow.addWindowListener(this);
        applicationWindow.add(createTable(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        applicationWindow.pack();
        applicationWindow.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        applicationWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createTable() {
        String[] columns = new String[] {
                "Id", "Name", "Hourly Rate", "Part Time"
        };

        //actual data for the table in a 2d array
        Object[][] data = new Object[30][5];
        for ( int i=0;i<30;i++) {
            data[i][0] = i;
            data[i][1] = "user"+i;
            data[i][2] = String.format("%.3f", Math.random() * 10.0);
            data[i][3] = Math.random() >0.5?true:false;
        }
        //create table with data
        JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        return scrollPane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new TablDemo());
    }
}

When you run the above code, the JFrame cannot be made smaller than its initial display size – but its size can be increased.

One observation in my testing is that the getSize() is returning the correct value after the pack().. Secondly, I did try using BorderLayout, but I then cannot get the control section and table section to display. Whichever is added last, overwrites the previous and only one displays. It would only work with GridBagLayout. Try adding the control section back and see what happens.

window.setMinimumSize(window.getSize()) still allows Windows 10 at 3840x2160 resolution to resizing to half the size set. I need to be able to detect that the window sizing has finished, and then reset the size. Anything else does not work.

A solution I have found to the minimum size issue is to add a MouseListener to the JScrollPane and JFrame that calls checkSize() on the mouseEntered() event. Adding the listener only to the frame seems to miss the event when the mouse travels into the JTable area. Not the prettiest, but it works.
private class MouseListen implements MouseListener{     
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            checkSize();
        }
    }


Note that a JFrame can also be resized via the keyboard, i.e. without using the mouse.
